# 3d model not rotating properly in threejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d, point-clouds

I have 3d tileset data (tileset.json),I am loading this tiles into three js scene using three-loader-3dtiles (https://github.com/nytimes/three-loader-3dtiles). it loads properly but its rotation is not working properly, can anybody help in this ? I attached code snippet for the same.

```
    const result = await Loader3DTiles.load(
      {
        url: `./tiles/pointcloud/tileset.json`,
        renderer: renderer,
        options: {
        dracoDecoderPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.137.0/examples/js/libs/draco',
        basisTranscoderPath: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.137.0/examples/js/libs/basis',
          pointCloudColoring: PointCloudColoring.RGB,
          shading:Shading.ShadedNoTexture,
          maximumScreenSpaceError: 6
        }
      }
    );
      console.log(result)
    const {model, runtime} = result;
    
    model.rotation.set(-Math.PI / 2 , 0 ,0);

    tilesRuntime = runtime;
    scene.add(model);
  }
```

I have uploaded videos of required rotation (nytimes.github.io/three-loader-3dtiles/examples/demos/cesium) and my output rotation on the drive, also shared react component and pointcloud tileset data which i used to render 3d model. please refer it, thanks in advance
drive link - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kraIt47yQyEo7dCI-BfEB3EJ77IYyv1X?usp=sharing
i used three-loader-3dtiles to load 3d pointclouds tiles in scene, i have Entwine format pointcloud also, this is also uploaded on the drive, if there is any method to load ept pointcloud in 3js scene, it also accepted for me.

Comment: You're gonna have to provide more information. What do you mean its rotation is not working properly? From what I can see, you're setting the rotation to -90 degrees along the X-axis. It's up to you to describe the problem and the desired result.

Comment: I have uploaded videos of required rotation (https://nytimes.github.io/three-loader-3dtiles/examples/demos/cesium/) and my output rotation on the drive, also shared react component and pointcloud tileset data which i used to render 3d model. please refer it, thanks in advance.
drive link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kraIt47yQyEo7dCI-BfEB3EJ77IYyv1X?usp=sharing